# paypal billing plan webhooks - next cycle starting

Tags: paypal

Is there any webhook or any event triggered when new billing plan's cycle is starting (like in stripe)? Or should I just interpret that if plan isn't cancelled it's paid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the hook.
It's the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED but with data.resource.billing_aggreement_id added. This is how we differ between normal payment and billing plan payment :D